# How to create a hibernate view of other databases?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, view

Good Morning, I'm in a problem!

My project is multitenant, I use SPRING JPA + SPRINGBOOT + POSTGRES. 
Where it contains a database manager and Each tenant has its own database.

The problem starts when inside the database of the tenant I have views of the data manager database.

For example, inside the database manager I have information to make the login of the users of a tenant. But in the database of each tenant should be able to have the information of their users. Where users within the tenant database could have more data!

What is the best way to do this? Should I create the view?

In addition, this application is very popular, so the idea is that the use of the database is quite dynamic.

Thank you in advance! any contribution will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the best solution will be to create views where you get all the data that you need and the data is already filtered for the tenant.

Edit:

You have to create the views on the database and then map it to read only Entities or just use it with SQL.

To have read only entities you can use Hibernates `@Immutable` annotation.

Please find more information in the Hibernate documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-immutability

Comment: Thanks Simon, you know what is the best way to create views in hibernate?considering my situation.

Comment: Thanks Simon, Do you know if there is any way to create these views automatically when the tables are created with hibernate?

Comment: No. But you could use Spring Boot schema.sql to create it

Comment: Sorry for so many questions. But I am quite new in the use of this technology. Is there any way to send data to schema.sql? For example, I would like to do a "where tenant_id=? ", Is it possible send data of idTenant?

Comment: No. The file is static. Otherwise you need a class on startup that listens to ApplicationReadyEvent